# What Is Causing Some Sites Are Embedded Within An Iframe in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Some sites are served within an `iframe` (only) on Chrome.

Here's an example of the source code of Digg.com served within an Iframe:

```html
<html class="gr__digg_com">
<head>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://digg.com/"/>
    </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ibnads.xl.co.id/ads-request?t=4&amp;j=2&amp;callback=iframe.jsonp454&amp;rnd=452&amp;a=http%3A%2F%2Fdigg.com%2F&amp;i=176791713"></script>
</head>
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="top-banner"></div>
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="left-banner"></div>
            <div id="content">
                <iframe id="main-frame" frameborder="0" style="width: 1333px; border: 0px; height: 8200px;" src="http://digg.com/"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="right-banner"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-banner"></div>
    </div>      
    <script type="text/javascript">p={'t':'4', 'i':'176791713'};</script>
    <script src="http://ibnads.xl.co.id:8004/COMMON/js/if_low_20150915.min.js"></script>
</body>
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" id="abs-top-frame" src="chrome-extension://flliilndjeohchalpbbcdekjklbdgfkk/html/top.html?1457289833178#minimized" style="position: fixed !important; z-index: 2147483647 !important;overflow: hidden !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; right: 0px !important; width: 0px !important; height: 0px !important; max-height: none !important; min-height: 0px !important; margin: 0px auto !important; padding: 0px !important; border: 0px !important; display: none !important; background-color: transparent !important;"></iframe>
<span class="gr__tooltip"><span class="gr__tooltip-content"></span><i class="gr__tooltip-logo"></i><span class="gr__triangle"></span></span>
</html>
```

The actual Digg.com content is embedded within`<iframe id="main-frame">`.

This causes an ugly extra vertical scroll bar.

The URL in the address bar is still digg.com.

I tried to visit the sites (digg.com and some other sites) in Firefox, and they look fine.

I suspect that it's caused by a browser extension, but I don't know what it is.

Here are all browser extensions I have installed on Chrome:

- Alexa Traffic Rank
- Avira Browse Safety
- Google Docs
- Google Docs Offline
- Google Mail Checker
- Google Sheets
- Google Slides
- Grammarly
- Instapaper
- Wikiwand

Does anyone know why some sites are being served within an Iframe on Chrome?

Comment: Try disabling all your plugins and then re-enabling them one at a tiem to find which one is causing the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can uncover the culprit by looking at the source of the offending iframe:
`src="chrome-extension://flliilndjeohchalpbbcdekjklbdgfkk/html/top.html?1457289833178#minimized”`

In `chrome://extensions`, you can turn on the developer mode, and this will show the id of each extension.  Then you can search through for this id `flliilndjeohchalpbbcdekjklbdgfkk`, but this turns out not to be necessary.

The chrome store organizes things by their id, so you can go to
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flliilndjeohchalpbbcdekjklbdgfkk
and find out that it’s Avira Browser Safety.

Answer (score 2):

I had this `iframe` as well. The Avira Browser Safety extension is causing it.

Uninstall it and the `iframe` on top of the window is gone.